# Mongodb Node.js Get count of inserted documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get the count of inserted records without making a repeated call to `db.collection.count()`.

My code

```
exports.save = function(json) {
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/apps';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      var collection = db.collection("apps");
      collection.insert(json, {w: 1}, function(err, records){
        console.log("Inserted : "+records.count() );
      });
    });
};
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Comment: You probably can't, the `insert` statement returns a `WriteResult` object that only contains the number of elements affected, not the total present, you'd have to call `collection.count()` for that.

Comment: Affected not mean Inserted?

Comment: The records variable should be an array, so you could do records.length

Comment: records.length() gives undefined on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insert() function takes an insertWriteOpCallback with an insertWriteOpResult in it.

So there is a property `insertedCount` which is the total amount of documents inserted.
Replace `.count()` with `.insertedCount`.

Source: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpResult